# How to set active class to second image for Cycle2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-cycle2

My all item has `cycle-pager-active` class but I just want to give them to images not div that's why I found a why I want to add active class my second element in `#single-pager` so I have to ask how can I do this ?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".mySlideShow").cycle({
       pauseOnHover: true,
       pager: "#single-pager",
       pagerTemplate: "<img src='{{children.0.src}}' width='70' height='70'>",
       slides: ".item"
    });
  
});
```

```css
.mySlideShow img{
  width:700px;
}
#single-pager img {
  margin:10px;
}
.cycle-pager-active{
  border:3px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="mySlideShow">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://cdn.anitur.com/web/images/h494/2017-03/otel_armonia-holiday-village-spa_tZuhzJnp6BDndutoN1lV.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

  <div class="item">
      <img src="http://cdn.anitur.com/web/images/h494/2017-03/otel_armonia-holiday-village-spa_M6XtiCxv8AvkGako7aHr.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://cdn.anitur.com/web/images/h494/2017-07/otel_armonia-holiday-village-spa_EOUfYFhHhV3UoxBxYTAr.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
  
<div id="single-pager">
    <div class="thumbnail-expand"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/2.1.6/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
```

[Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JyOPZq)

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean. As much as I saw, the images have the class `cycle-pager-active` not the `div`s right?

Comment: no  my first div (`.thumbnail-expand`) has cycle-pager-active class and I just onyl set for images

Comment: If you want to add a class only fir the images, give them. Then you can set style to the active image. Let's say you gave the images the class `image` you can set the style for `.image.cycle-pager-active`.

Comment: and this is the question how can I give class only images ? thanks by the way

Comment: I'm using this option area `slideActiveClass:'img.cycle-slide-active'` but nothing change http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/

Comment: by the way I'm talking about for thumbnails

Comment: Now I understand.. By images you mean the thumbnails, not the images itself. Well, I'm not sure you can, but, you can use the selector `img.cycle-pager-active`. This way only the `img` tags will be affect.

Comment: So could you give an example about how to  do ? I tried to give `img.cycle-pager-active` but nothing change ? maybe I set wrong

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that you need to set the property:

```
pager: "#single-pager .thumbnail-expand",
```

instead of

```
pager: "#single-pager",
```

When the property is `#single-pager` the plugin **adds** the thumbnails to the div. So instead of 3 `div`s you have 4. So the plugin start from the first `div` which is not thumbnail.

Like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".mySlideShow").cycle({
    pauseOnHover: true,
    pager: "#single-pager .thumbnail-expand",
    pagerTemplate: "<img src='{{children.0.src}}' width='70' height='70' />",
    slides: ".item"
  });
});
```

```css
.mySlideShow img {
  width: 700px;
}

#single-pager img {
  margin: 10px;
}


/* add this -> */

img.cycle-pager-active {
  border: 3px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="mySlideShow">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://cdn.anitur.com/web/images/h494/2017-03/otel_armonia-holiday-village-spa_tZuhzJnp6BDndutoN1lV.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://cdn.anitur.com/web/images/h494/2017-03/otel_armonia-holiday-village-spa_M6XtiCxv8AvkGako7aHr.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://cdn.anitur.com/web/images/h494/2017-07/otel_armonia-holiday-village-spa_EOUfYFhHhV3UoxBxYTAr.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="single-pager">
  <div class="thumbnail-expand"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.cycle2/2.1.6/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you but I don't think that you understand mu @Mosh, I explain now..if you pay attention my thumbnails and main image you will see they are different I mean if I click first thumbnail my main image is changcing with different image // sorry my bad english